# Anyone in this group working on Redis as a Database

Tags: redis

I am working on a migration project from Oracle to Redis. The business logic or the CRUD operations implemented in PL/SQL will be written in Lua scripts which will be called from Java using jedis.

1. What is the best way to deploy these Lua scripts?

   - Can I load/register the scripts in Redis DB manually and then call them using evalsha method from java? – What are the possible issues I get?
   - Can I create an API with all the scripts and load them from java code and use eval method to call them.
2. If I use the master-slave architecture with the Sentinel (1 master, 2 slaves, and 3 sentinels) for high availability with automatic failover. Do I need to use 3 servers for these or can I go with one server with 3 ports?

Comment: Don't ask to ask. Just ask. What is your question? Thousands of people on this site use Redis.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way to deploy these Lua scripts?

You should be using `EVALSHA` to determine if the script has been loaded into Redis. If not, use `SCRIPT LOAD`. Then you don't have to keep sending the script contents to Redis every time you execute it.

> Can I load/register the scripts in Redis DB manually and then call
>   them using evalsha method from java? – What are the possible issues I
>   get? Can I create an API with all the scripts and load them from java
>   code and use eval method to call them.

You can definitely load the scripts manually. However, its probably better for the application to handle when the script isn't in Redis as a fail-safe. How you get the contents is up to you.

> If I use the master-slave architecture with the Sentinel (1 master, 2
>   slaves, and 3 sentinels) for high availability with automatic
>   failover. Do I need to use 3 servers for these or can I go with one
>   server with 3 ports?

It probably depends on your needs. Having everything live in the same server makes you have a single point of failure -- if that server goes down or is offline, you lose the ability to interact with Redis.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  One more question is the sha value for a script is the same in all the environments like development or production?

Comment: Yep, it is the SHA1 of the script contents, which only changes if you change the script.